# Set Program to use LIBXML_PARSEHUGE

Tags: libxml2, xmlsec

I am using the commandline app xmlsec to encrypt and decrypt files. I got an XML File with a node at 40 MB of size. 
I already found out i need to set

```
LIBXML_PARSEHUGE
```

to parse nodes bigger than 10 MB

Does anyone know how to enable this?
I searched the source code of xmlsec for the Parser init, but couldn't find a way to integrate the option
Do i have to set this inside the source and recompile it? When so, do i have to recompile libxml or xmlsec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i found the solution and post it here just in case anyone needs this sometime
In

```
src/Parser.c 
xmlDocPtr xmlSecParseFile(const char *filename){}
```

Contains this

```
/* enable parsing of XML documents with large text nodes */
xmlCtxtUseOptions (ctxt, XML_PARSE_HUGE);
```

Orinigally, the second line is commented out. You have to uncomment it and recompile the tool

Answer (score 0):

You can also activate the parameter via the `simplexml_load_string` function itself:

```
simplexml_load_string($xmlString,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);
```